# How do I show that set G with operation ∗ on ℤ Z is group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do I show that set G with operation $ *$ defined on  $ \mathbb{Z}$ is group?
This is not a homework question, I just want to know general procedure for proving this. For example:

$*$ is defined as: $ a*b=a+(-1)^ab $.

If I understand it right, I have to show:

1. closure under $*$
2. associativity
3. find inverse element for every $ a \in G $
4. find identity element

How do I do that?

**Edit**:
What have I tried so far:

1. **closure**:

If we take two integers, and perform $*$, result is clearly integer (integer +  - integer is an integer)

2. **associativity**:

I need to show that $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$

$(a*b)*c = (a+(-1)^ab)*c=a+(-1)^ab+c(-1)^{a+b(-1)^a}$
$a*(b*c) = a+(-1)^a(b+ c(-1)^b) = a+(-1)^ab + c(-1)^{a+b}$

So it should be that:  $ c(-1)^{a+b(-1)^a} = c(-1)^{a+b} $

Left side is : $c(-1)^{a+b(-1)^a}=c(-1)^a(-1)^{b(-1)^a}=c(-1)^a(-1)^{b}$

and right side: $c(-1)^{a+b}=c(-1)^a(-1)^b$ !

so it's equal.

4. **identity**:

$a*e=a$

$a+e(-1)^a=a$

$e(-1)^a=0$

$(-1)^{anything}$ can't be zero, so $e=0$

3. **inverses:**

$a*i=e$

$a+i(-1)^a=0$

$i(-1)^a=-a$

$i = -a(-1)^{-a}$

If we plug it back into equation it gives identity element!

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand what $G$ is. It cannot be an arbitrary set.

Comment: You asked for general procecure so see for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736055/proving-g-is-a-group-under-a-specific-operation?rq=1

Comment: Compute a*0. Compute a*a and a*(-a) for odd,even a.

Comment: You should switch steps 3 and 4.  You need the identity before you can find inverses.

Comment: Also thank you @paw88789 for pointing that out!