# Properties of the composition law $a @ b= ab + b + a$ on the real numbers

Tags: group-theory

The operation $@$ is defined on the real numbers as $a @ b= ab + b + a$

a) Show that $0$ is an identity for the operation.

b) Show that some real numbers have inverses under the operation.

c) Find a counter-example to show that, for this operation inverses do not exist for all the real numbers.

I have so far came to understand as far as: $a, b,c \in \mathbb{R}$
Identity: Ia= aI= a
@ b I= @ b + b + I
I @ b = I b + b + I

Comment: Well, just write it out.  What is $0@1$, for example?  $0@7$?  $0@b$?

Comment: To prove $0$ is the identity, show that $a@0=0@a=a$ for an arbitrary choice of $a$

Comment: To understand (and prove) in one strike all these properties (and how your TA built their exercise), note that $@$ is really the ordinary product in disguise, since $$(a@b)+1=(a+1)\cdot(b+1)$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $G$ is a group under a specific operation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736055/proving-g-is-a-group-under-a-specific-operation)

Answer (score 3):

> a) Show that 0 is an identity for the operation.

(I write $\circ$ instead of @)

We have $a\circ b:=ab+b+a$. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary, then:

$0\circ a=0a+a+0=a$

$a\circ 0=a0+0+a=a$

> b) Show that some real numbers have inverses under the operation.

We have to find a pair $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ sucht that $a\circ b=0$ and $b\circ a=0$
First of all $a\circ b=ab+a+b=ba+b+a=b\circ a$.

It has to be $ab+a+b=0$. $a(b+1)=-b\Leftrightarrow a=\frac{-b}{b+1}$ for $b\neq -1$

Therefor $a$ has to be of the form $\frac{-b}{b+1}$, to be an inverse of $b\neq -1$.

$\frac{-b}{b+1}b+b+\frac{-b}{b+1}=\frac{-b^2-b}{b+1}+\frac{b^2+b}{b+1}=\frac{b^2-b^2+b-b}{b+1}=0$

> c) Find a counter-example to show that, for this operation inverses do not exist for all the real numbers.

For $a=-1$ there can not be an inverse.

$-1\circ b=-b+b-1=-1$

Note, that it does not depend on $b$. So there is no chance, that it ever will be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note this operation is commutative, so $A$ has an inverse under this operation if and only if there exists $x$ such that $\;a@x=ax+x+a=0$.

Can you determine for which $a$ this equation has a solution?