# Abstract Algebra: Prove if it is an abelian group. Need Clarification

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

I need clarification of what it means when they say Let $S = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}$. Does this mean all the real numbers except $-1$. 
Problem: Let $S = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}$ and define a binary operation on $S$ by $a*b = a + b + ab$. Prove that $(S,*)$ is an abelian group.

What I know: I know I need to show closure, identity, inverse, assoc, and comm.

For closure I want to prove using contrapositive. So I know I have to start with assuming that $a*b$ is not in S and show that $a$ is not in S or $b$ is not in $S$. But I'm really confused with $S = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}$. Because I know I can say $a*b = a+b+ab$ if it was in S but I'm assuming it is not.

Comment: You know that the reals are closed by sum and multiplication, and so $a * b$ will always lie on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $a * b \not \in S$ can only occur when $a * b = -1$.

Comment: Note that $ab+a+b=(a+1)(b+1)-1$, and consider some of the identities related to $0$ in $\Bbb R$...

Comment: Your question is already has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736055/proving-g-is-a-group-under-a-specific-operation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Have you tried calculating a few things with this operation? Like what do you get for $0*0$, $1*1$, or $-2*-2$? What about $-2*0$ or $10*1$? Just so a few random ones. Then you can try some general stuff, like $0*x$. Familiarise yourself with the operation. Only once you've done that should you try to prove general properties like associativity and commutativity. It will probably be a lot easier by then.

Comment: Here's a hint: if $a, b \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}$, then $(a + 1)(b + 1) \neq 0$.